# computing duration of a wav file

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I am trying to edit a wav file using c++ by directly reading its binary data. I have written the file's header as follows:

```
struct header{    
char chunk_id[4];
int chunk_size;
char format[4];
char subchunk1_id[4];
int subchunk1_size;
short int audio_format;
short int num_channels;
int sample_rate;            
int byte_rate;
short int block_align;
short int bits_per_sample;
char subchunk2_id[4];
int subchunk2_size;
 };
```

Now how to compute the maximum duration of the sound track assuming that the header's data is already loaded in some variable?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a duration in seconds (rounded down) is good enough, you can simply use

```
int durationInSeconds(struct header* hdr)
{
    int numSamples = hdr->subchunk2_size /
                         (hdr->num_channels * (hdr->bits_per_sample/8));
    int durationSeconds = numSamples / hdr->sample_rate;
    return durationSeconds;
}
```

`subchunk2_size` gives you the number of bytes of audio data.  Dividing this by the product of the number of samples and byte rate (note: `bits_per_sample` gives you the number of bits in a single sample for a single channel - this is different from `byte_rate` in `header`) gives you a total number of samples.

`sample_rate` is the number of samples per second so dividing the total number of samples by this gives you the total duration in seconds.